# iOS: subclass UIView in a tableview row

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, tableview, subclass

I am trying to set this custom view in every single row of my tableview.
In my interface builder I add a UIView in the UITableViewCell and I link the IBOutlet. So I subclass it to `CircleView`

this is its class

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2,y: rect.height/2), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = Constants.defaultCircleFillColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.5
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func setColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

but when I try to call the `setColor` func in `cellForRowAt` delegate, nothing happen.
Is there a way to manage its stroke color?

this is the `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let remote_row: RemoteType = sections[indexPath.section].cellData[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: remote_row.identifier) as? RemoteCell {
            switch remote_row {
            case .Item(circleColor: let color, text: let title):
                cell.configCell(circleColor: color, description: title)
            }
            return cell
        } else {
            fatalError("Unknown identifier")
        }
    }
```

and the RemoteCell:

```
class RemoteCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: CircleView!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingButton: UIButton!

    func configCell(circleColor: UIColor, description: String) {
        title.text = description
        circleView.setColor(UIColor.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rather include your code for `cellForRowAt`, since the error most probably resides there and not in the custom `CircleView` class itself.

Comment: Maybe the `setColor` is called before `draw`. Please try to check it with log or break point.

Comment: Are you sure the method isn't being called? Have you put a breakpoint in the method to see whether it is being called or not?

Comment: I added breakpoints... the problem is that `setColor` is called before of `draw`

Comment: @CrazyDev please include code for `cellForRowAt`. I am pretty sure that the issue is with not properly initialising the view, but just trying to cast a `UIView` to `CircleView`, but without the relevant code, I cannot be certain.

Comment: @DávidPásztor , yes I update my pos with that

Comment: @CrazyDev it seems like you do all the cell setup in your function called `configCell`, so please include that one as well, since `setColor` is not called anywhere directly from `cellForRowAt`. I only asked for that function, because in your question you mentioned that this is where the function is called from...

Comment: @DávidPásztor done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated in comments, by setting up breakpoints, you realised that `setColor` is called before `draw` would be called. This is expected behaviour due to the drawing cycle of `UIView`.

As the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) states in the *The View Drawing Cycle* part,

> View drawing occurs on an as-needed basis. When a view is first shown,
>   or when all or part of it becomes visible due to layout changes, the
>   system asks the view to draw its contents. For views that contain
>   custom content using UIKit or Core Graphics, the system calls the
>   view’s  draw(_:)  method.

This means that in `cellForRowAt` the `draw` method is not yet called, since the cell itself is not even returned and not displayed on the screen. You could fix this issue, by setting up a new instance variable for your `CircleView` class, that stores the colour you want to use in `setColor` and use this colour directly in the `draw` method. In `cellForRowAt` just assign the colour you used as an input to `setColor` before to this new instance property and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: great solution! Thanks, I did not think about it!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

the draw method is going to get executed when your tableView draws the cell, so the color change is going to get overriden and set to clear.

try something like this:

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var myColor:UIColor = UIColor.clear

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {    
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle:(.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = Constants.defaultCircleFillColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = myColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.5
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func setColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        myColor = color
        // shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to reference `self` in Swift unless it's to remove ambiguity or within an escaping closure. simply using `myColor = color` is enough.

Comment: I agree, it's just a habit

Comment: Also, since the `CircleView` is a direct subclass of `UIView` you don't need the call to `super.draw(rect)` as the default implementation does nothing.